# Show and hide certain markers

Tags: views, google-maps

I am using GMAP module on Drupal7 for Google Maps. I am using it with Views module. Have created map view with markers from content type. Everything works fine.

Now I want to be able to show and hide some markers (not all) based on for example some category or any node field. How can I manipulate (just show and hide some of them) markers outside the view? Or maybe there is a possibility to do it within view?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to show and hide specific markers on my full map under Administration » Structure » Views » Full Map View. I added a filter that showed markers based the Content: Author uid. Then I set the pages I wanted to show to have one author and the other locations that I didn't want to display to a different author. This article helped me figure it out: https://groups.drupal.org/node/19614

Hope that helps you.